# Using Xwiki with existing Angular application

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, xwiki

I have web service based web application with front build in angularjs and web service built on grails. Now I need to add a wiki app to integrate into the existing application. I want to use XWiki as a service. So is it possible to extract out only the API from XWiki with my own user credentials and roles to work with. I can't seem to figure out these issues with current documentation.

Also can you suggest other lightweight alternatives to Xwiki which supports REST ???

Comment: If You want solution for wiki markup renderer and similar area, I use many years info.bliki.wiki. This IS NOT full Wiki server. Very good object design (i.e. with good Model concept). Markup is compatible with mediawiki (Wikipedia). I had analysed XWiki years ago, was veeeery big

Comment: 2. Over good designed Bliki data structure  (Model, database etc) You can implement REST with general libraries. Read in bliki community, maybe now they have REST? I haven't such needs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need some sort of hackable rest app with support  authentication and so on. I don't have much time to create all the underlying architecture by myself.

Comment: I understand, i had idea REST is generally known (and trendy), supported in Eclipse etc, java wiki engines are out of main stream, I remember how hard find good one (and living). REST cannot be (almost ;) ) generated in popular tools?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can extract data from XWiki very easily using the REST API, see http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Features/XWikiRESTfulAPI

Another strategy is to write the AngularJS app directly inside XWiki. There are some examples available here:

- AngularJS Demo: http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/AngularJSDemo
- AngularJS Todo app: https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/application-angular-todo
- Small AngularJS app that does a live rendering of wiki markup: https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/angular-rendering

Hope it helps